# Appium: Right way to find elements on Android screen

Tags: c#, android, appium, automated-tests, selendroid

I want to use [Appium](http://appium.io/slate/en/master/?ruby#toc_0) to make automated testing for my Android app. I am writing tests in C#. I've done fair share in my searching but couldn't find a good documentation explaining how to access elements on Android screen. I know there are methods like `FindElementsByXPath`, `FindElementById`, `FindElementByName` etc, but I am not able to use those methods right way as I am getting exceptions. Please read questions below:

1) To use `FindElementsByXPath` method I need to know `PageSource` in advance which can be obtained only using `driver.PageSource`. Is there any convenient way to know `PageSource` prior to running tests so that I can pass XPath string as a parameter to `FindElementsByXPath`?

2) I've `EditTextView` on Android screen. In layout it is declared as follows:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone|flagNoExtractUi" 
        >
```

How shall I access this `EditTextView` using it's id i.e. 'password' while writing test?

3) Is it possible to set text to `EditTextView` programatically? If yes, how to do it?

Thanks for taking time to read whole question. If you have any resources explaining how to access and manipulate elements on Android screen while writing [Appium](http://appium.io/slate/en/master/?ruby#toc_0) tests, please provide me the same.

Answer (score 0):

For Android apps I use UIAutomatorViewer to view all elements on an app. It's part of the Android sdk and displays different identifiers, including id, class name, and text.

Answer (score 0):

First of all - what is you application under test? Is it a web app or a native app? Do you run web browser on your Androud device?

Answer (score -1):

You can find "uiautomatorviewer", a batch file inside the Tools folder in your SDK folder. You have to use that one. From that u can able to capture the screen shot of either device or emulator and find the ID. Using UI-automator you can get Resource-id, class-name ect. for an element.